# Reproducing figure 15.10 in Elements of statistical Learning

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, bias-variance-tradeoff

I am really struggling to recreate both figures. I am coding in R.

For example for the squared bias my idea is the following:

What we are interested in in theory is

$
E_X[Bias(f^{(T,X)})] = E_X[f(X) - E_T(f^{(T,X)})] \quad (1)
$

Where $f^{(.,.)}$ is our random forest.

Now at a fixed $x$:

$
Bias(f^{(T,x)})=f(x)-E_T(f^{(x,T)})
$

Where: $f^{(.,T)}$ is the predictor we built using training data ( T ), $f(x)$ is the formula they gave in the book, $( (\frac{1}{\sqrt{50}})\sum(X_j) , ( X_i \sim N(0,1) $).

Now since we have 500 training data sets, we can approximate

$( E_T(f^{(x,T)}) $) at a fixed $x$, by using the Monte Carlo estimate. (In other words we build 500 predictors with 500 different training sets, compute the prediction for this particular $x$ and average). Name this estimate $P(x)$.

$
Bias_{estimate}(f^{(T,x)})=f(x)-P(x)
$

Now we use the testing data (we have 600 such testing data) to approximate the Expected value in (1).

So we "output" for our squared bias:

$
\frac{1}{600}\sum_{j=1}^{600}[f(x_j)-P(x_j)]^2
$

where the $x_{j}$ are the testing points.

I just want to know if my idea is correct and/or if anyone has ever reproduced this figure and could provide some help.

Much appreciated!
[image]

Comment: This question will be easier to read & more likely to get answers if you use math typsetting. More information: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference